# Reading and write on the same excel file with ruby

Tags: ruby, excel

I'm looking for a way to reading and writing on same excel file in ruby. I saw a this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898449/how-to-read-from-and-write-to-the-same-excel-file) but the suggestions doesn't work for me.

I tried to use Roo gem, but this not allow to write. I tried to use the Spreadsheet gem too, but this doesn't read Xlsx files.

Is there a way to reading and write on same excel file in ruby?

Comment: There's always the Win32OLE gem for interacting with the Office OLE objects, if your on Windows. If your not, you need to decode it yourself (That's a whole lot of hacking, it took the libreoffice team a very long time).

Comment: [JRuby + POI](https://github.com/kameeoze/jruby-poi) is a powerful option that I've used successfully.

Comment: Not sure if I understand, are you opening the file read-only ? can you add the option 'w' when opening it (like for File.open("somefile",'w') ?

Comment: Hi Mark, jruby can be an alternative, but i think this moment will be complicate make the necessary changes.

Comment: @oma, no, i'm not opening the read-only file. The problem is to write in a excel file.

Comment: I need to see code. Manipulating the file is the most common use case and should work. Please make a supersimple example, make sure it reproduces the problem and update the Q. Good exercise anyways :)

Answer (score 3):

try [rubyXL](https://github.com/gilt/rubyXL)

Ruby lib for reading/writing/modifying .xlsx and .xlsm files

Comment: Thanks Rovetz, the rubyXL is working ok to read the data, but there is a bug when i go to save the xlsx. "can't convert Symbol into Integer" - lib/rubyXL/writer/styles_writer.rb:26:in `[]'. Do you know something about this?